# Website files (documents) hosting for download

Tags: web-hosting, download, files, cloud

I have a website (on development) of learning resources (school exams and courses), which contains links to pdf docs (~ 2000) each user can read the document online or download it, having to start with a shared hosting plan, the bandwitch is unmetered and not really unlimited,
My question is , is there a hosting services for documents so i can put my files in their servers and get links for them, (free or even paid)
As a new web developer i checked Amazon S3 and Google cloud but their pricing is lil bit ambiguous for me after reading them.